# What optimizations could I apply to speed up this query?

Tags: database, optimization, query-optimization

I'm creating a simple business analytics application for the company I work at and have a 100mb csv file of sales transactions from the last 6 years that I've parsed into a number of databases.

One of the figures I want to display in my application are turnover and profit per customer per day, so I have a while loop that looks like the following:

```
while(start_date < current_date)
    {
        SELECT SUM(profit), SUM(turnover) FROM sales WHERE date = @date
    }
```

So, I'm running that query on a table with a few hundred thousand rows as many times per day as there are customers every day for 6 years.

I was always led to believe any work that can be carried out in the DB, should be - which is why I've used the SUM queries to total the columns.

What other optimizations can I make? At the moment it is taking... well, I couldn't tell you since it's been running for the last hour on an 8GB, quad core server and looks like its at around 2-3%.

I'm using SQL Server Compact Edition and it's a winforms application in C#/.NET but the db is obviously the bottleneck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try introducing summary table where you'll have daily stats. update that summary table [with triggers or application logic] whenever you add some more data to the sales table.

Comment: That's what I'm planning to do for updates. I probably should have explained that in my original question - the actual question is with regards to how I might optimize and speed up the initial query since it's taking donkeys years. :)

Comment: do you have index on the date column?

Answer (score 1):

I would only run this (modified) query once and loop through the result set.  It should be way faster.

```
SELECT 
    customer, date, SUM(profit), SUM(turnover) 
FROM 
    sales 
WHERE 
    date < current_date 
GROUP BY 
    customer, date
ORDER BY
    customer, date

for each (row in resultset) {
    //process customer/date
}
```